# 2.74 not using all CPU cores when baking rigid body physics

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, performance, baking

I noticed during baking physics (with 2,500 rigid bodies in a solidified cylinder) that, instead of using all 8 cores on my AMD FX-8150 CPU, it maxes one out at 100%, but then passes the baton onto another one, which goes at 100%, etc. but never seems to use them synchronously.

[image: system performance graph]

Baking takes a while with that many rigid bodies; is there a way to configure Blender to use all 100% of CPU when baking physics?

(Running Blender 2.74 x64 on Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 x64)

Comment: I guess rigid body baking just isn't multithreaded. Also cycles doesn't handle physics simulations, it only does the rendering.

Comment: @gandalf3, if so, is there any way to... I dunno... enable multithreading?

Comment: @TravLR See this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27125/is-physics-calculation-multithreading-possible/27155#27155

Comment: @TravLR Not unless you count writing it yourself in C ;) It's a feature which just doesn't exist (yet).

Comment: @gandalf3, heh fair enough. :) Well, if/when it becomes a part of future Blender iterations, it'll be a huge benefit.

Comment: @RayMairlot, thanks for the suggestion; though perhaps a little more involved than I was looking to tread.

Comment: This also seems to be the case for 2.76.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a known limitation of Blender (both the past 2.74 version and the current 2.76, at this time). The Cycles engine just doesn't (yet) have multithreading capability for baking rigid body physics. (Possibly soft body physics, also, though I haven't tested.)